# how to hide html content of the tab with the tab in extjs?

Tags: extjs, tabs, hide, disabled-control

I created this simple example with two tabs, the first tab1 i want to make it disappear myTab.child('# tab1').Tab.hide(), but your html content does not disappear with the tab1. And when I enable the html content of tab2 tab1 is on the html of tab2. Why?

[See this sample](http://bit.ly/11fvTa4)

Thanks in Advanced,
Cláudio.

Comment: can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`setActiveTab`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-method-setActiveTab) to switch tabs (or `getLayout().setActiveItem()`).

From the help:

```
var card1 = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {itemId: 'card-1'});
var card2 = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {itemId: 'card-2'});
var panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    layout: 'card',
    activeItem: 0,
    items: [card1, card2]
});
// These are all equivalent
panel.getLayout().setActiveItem(card2);
panel.getLayout().setActiveItem('card-2');
panel.getLayout().setActiveItem(1);
```

Comment: Thank you A1rPun your example was very cool, but I wanted to do it that way here: [Example](http://bit.ly/ZvgNrw)